# Export same row multiple times with ImpEx

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

Is it possible to export the same row multiple times based on an attribute of the item?
Let's say for example that the `CategoryModel` has a `List<ProductModel>`.

How can I do an export using ImpEx to get something like this:

```
| category_code | product_code |
|------------------------------|
|     cat1      |     prod1    |
|------------------------------|
|     cat1      |     prod2    |
|------------------------------|
|     cat1      |     prod3    |
|------------------------------|
```

Is it possible to achieve that using translators? The best I could do with them is the following:

```
| category_code | product_code |
|------------------------------|
|     cat1      |    prod1     |
|               |    prod2     |
|               |    prod3     |
|------------------------------|
```

**EDIT:** The ImpEx header is this:

```
INSERT_UPDATE Category; code; @product_translated[translator = ...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For lists, I'm not sure if there's an easy way to do that.

For relations, you can simply use the type. To get the the list of product-category mapping, you can do this:

```
UPDATE CategoryProductRelation;source(code,catalogversion(catalog(id),version));target(code,catalogversion(catalog(id),version))
```

source will be the category, while target will be the product.

Comment: Oh, this will help me more than you think :D Thank you.